# change default controller for module in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can change default controller of generated module
DefaultController to another controller

```
'modules' => [
    'product' => [
        'class' => 'backend\modules\product\product',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [defaultRoute](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-module#$defaultRoute-detail) property, for example:

```
'modules' => [
    'product' => [
        'class' => 'backend\modules\product\product',
        'defaultRoute' => 'your-controller'
    ],
],
```